# pyrogram error : (struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 263 bytes )

Tags: python, pyrogram

I made a program in pyrogram it is running fine with the previous account of telegram but when someone login with new account it gives error to update the app i have updated it and also changed the code to login it worked but when i used that session string in my app it is not working

here is the code how i created the session

```
# Session creator

from pyrogram import Client
import os


# os.system('pip install --upgrade pip')
# os.system('pip install Pyrogram==1.2.20')


banner = """
                   _                                   _             
 ___  ___  ___ ___(_) ___  _ __     ___ _ __ ___  __ _| |_ ___  _ __ 
/ __|/ _ \/ __/ __| |/ _ \| '_ \   / __| '__/ _ \/ _` | __/ _ \| '__|
\__ \  __/\__ \__ \ | (_) | | | | | (__| | |  __/ (_| | || (_) | |   
|___/\___||___/___/_|\___/|_| |_|  \___|_|  \___|\__,_|\__\___/|_|   
                                                                     
"""
print(banner)
print("""String Generator. ==> Get Your Api Id & Api Hash From my.telegram.org and fill accordingly."""
      )
print("")

while True:
    try:
        APP_ID = int(input("Enter APP ID - "))
        API_HASH = input("Enter API HASH - ")

        with Client(":memory:", APP_ID, API_HASH) as c:
            print("")
            print("This is your STRING_SESSION. Please Keep It safe.")
            print("")
            c.storage.SESSION_STRING_FORMAT = ">B?256sQ?"
            session = c.export_session_string()
            with open("accounts.csv", "a")as file:
                file.writelines(str(APP_ID) + "," +
                                str(API_HASH) + "," + str(session) + "\n")
            # print(session)
            print("added")
            print("\n\n\n")
    except KeyboardInterrupt as error:
        print("stopped")
        break
exit()
```

and when i use this session in my program it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ak/Desktop/development/bots/pyrogramplugins/multiuserbot/userbot/randombot.py", line 161, in <module>
    ac.start()
  File "/home/ak/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py", line 56, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/ak/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/start.py", line 53, in start
    is_authorized = await self.connect()
  File "/home/ak/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/auth/connect.py", line 39, in connect
    await self.load_session()
  File "/home/ak/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py", line 669, in load_session
    await self.storage.open()
  File "/home/ak/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/storage/memory_storage.py", line 38, in open
    dc_id, test_mode, auth_key, user_id, is_bot = struct.unpack(
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 267 bytes
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.